# solutionEvents.Opened is not getting fired in Visual Studio VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I am developing an Extension for visual studio and "Solution Open" event need to be triggered once a solution is opened. Because I need to add a command to run when the solution opens.

For that I have used solutionEvents.Opened event handler and it is working fine when open solutions using below approaches

- using "Open Solution" dialog of visual studio
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM38I.png)
- Visual Studio File Menu > Recent Solutions or Projects > solution.

But strangely solutionEvents.Opened event handler is not working when open solutions using below approaches

- using .sln file double click
- right clicking visual studio icon in windows task bar and click solution name to open solution.
- windows start menu > visual studio 2019 > click solution name

I would like to know the reason behind that.

```
public void Initialize(Package package)
{
    solutionEvents.Opened += SolutionEvents_SolutionOpened;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution might already have been loaded when your package initializes: https://github.com/madskristensen/SolutionLoadSample